# \hangindent does not work when using adjustwidth environment

Tags: indentation

I am trying to format part of a LaTeX document that should have the first line flush left, the second line should be indented, and then there should be a bullet list. Additionally, I would like to put some left and right padding around the block.

In order to apply the padding, I am trying to use the `changepage` package and `adjustwidth` environment. Unfortunately, what I find is that when I use `adjustwidth`, the effect of `hangindent` is nullified. I have tried many permutations of `\hangindent`, `\hangafter`, `\leftskip`, `\rightskip`, `\setlength`, etc. but have not yet seemed to find a combination that works.

Here is a minimum working example of both what the text should look like without padding and then the problem that is introduced when padding is added:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}

\section*{How it should look, though I'd like to add some padding to the left and right.}
\noindent \textbf{A title of some sort} \\
\hangindent=\parindent Some descriptive text \\
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{compactitem}
    \item Bullet point 1
    \item Bullet point 2
    \item Bullet point 3
\end{compactitem}  

\section*{Adding padding using adjustwidth causes the hanindent to fail.}
\begin{adjustwidth}{5em}{5em}
    \noindent \textbf{A title of some sort} \\
    \hangindent=\parindent Some descriptive text that should be indented.\\
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{compactitem}
        \item Bullet point 1
        \item Bullet point 2
        \item Bullet point 3
    \end{compactitem}  
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will find that the second instance of `Some descriptive text that should be indented` is flush left with `A title of some sort` on the previous line. It should, however, be indented to the same position as the bullets below it. If you don't see this problem, please message me and I can send the pdf through a private message/email.

Any advice or workarounds for this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it doesn't work: `adjustwidth` is a `list` environment in disguise, so it uses `\parshape` which wins over `\hangindent`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Kurt! Also, I am not sure what you're asking, I have `\begin{compactitem}` appearing a several lines after `\begin{adjustwidth}`. Even if moved things around, it doesn't fix anything.

I imagine that I can work around this by using a `minipage`, but I feel like that is overkill for just changing the margins/padding for a paragraph.

Comment: Generally it does not work with list environments (tested it with KOMA-Script’s `\addmargin`, chngpage's `\adjustwidth` - what you used – and `enumitem`). I wrote some time ago an e-mail to Will Robertson about that issue to be mentioned in the documentation of `hanging`, what uses `\hangindent`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should emulate the hanging indentation with a list, so that it can be properly nested in `adjustwidth`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{hanging}[1][\parindent]
  {\list{}{%
   \topsep\z@
    \listparindent\parindent
    \parsep\parskip
    \leftmargin=#1}%
    \item[]}
  {\endlist}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section*{How it should look, though I'd like to add some padding to the left and right.}
\noindent \textbf{A title of some sort}
\begin{hanging}
Some descriptive text
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Bullet point 1
  \item Bullet point 2
  \item Bullet point 3
\end{itemize}
\end{hanging}

\section*{Adding padding using adjustwidth}
\begin{adjustwidth}{5em}{5em}
\noindent \textbf{A title of some sort}
\begin{hanging}
Some descriptive text that should be indented.
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Bullet point 1
  \item Bullet point 2
  \item Bullet point 3
\end{itemize}  
\end{hanging}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

The `hanging` environment has an optional argument, the amount of hanging indentation.

I used the `enumitem` package, which is more powerful than `paralist`. In any case, adding `\\` before starting an itemized list is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up modifying your solution to better suit my needs. I used the `enumitem` package as your suggested (very useful) and was able to do everything I need through nested lists and selective use of `leftmargin`, `rightmargin`, `itemsep`, `label`, `beginpenalty`, and `midpenalty` options. Works perfectly and is now structurally correct as well.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for, but I get an `Undefined control sequence` error when I try implementing the code. Does the solution only work for lists? Or will it work on regular text as well?

Comment: @dayne It should work with any text inside. What's the undefined control sequence?

Comment: @egreg I will go back and try and replicate the error this afternoon, then post a question and give you think the link here. This is only my second day in LaTeX and I am still figuring things out. I was trying to use both `adjustwidth` and `hanging` inside a `newcommand`. I am not sure if that would cause a problem or not.